# JQuery UI dialog box is working on one server, but not working on another

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui

I have a simple list of links, so when each one is clicked, I should have a Dialog pop up with more information inside it that is obtained from DB and posted back into that dialog as json object.

Now problem, this very setup works on one of my servers and does not work on another. Both servers are running Apache and both servers have pretty similar in general except for one thing, first (the working one) is VPS and second one is shared host, I am really not sure if that has anything to do with it, but this is the only thing that is left for me to think of.

```
   <head>

<link rel=stylesheet href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/themes/start/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/jquery-1.8.2.min.js"></script>
<script>
function user_dialog(a,b){
    "undefined"!=typeof jQuery.ui?($("#dialog").attr("title","Detailed Information").html(a),
    $("#dialog").dialog({
        modal:true,
        width:400,
        buttons: {
            Cancel: function() {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                },
                Download: function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    window.location=b
                    }
                    }
                    }
                    ))
                    :window.location=b}

function user_notice(a){
    download_link=$(a).attr("href");
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"/includes/json.php",
        data:"action=reminder&thepath="+download_link,
        dataType:"json",
        error:function(){
            window.location=download_link
            },
        success:function(a){
            1==a.status&&user_dialog(a.html,download_link);
            }
            })
            };
</script>



</head>

<body>
<div class="bb_button"><a class="bb_xls" href=" " rel="nofollow" onClick=" user_notice(this,''); return false;">Download Now</a></div>
<div id="dialog" style="display:none;"> <p>This is the default dialog which is useful for displaying information. The dialog window can be moved, resized and closed with the 'x' icon.</p>
</div>
<div id="g_plus_message"></div>


<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js?ver=1.10.1"></script>

</body>
```

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean "not working"? Do you have any alerts, errors, debug info?

Comment: No nothing at all no alerts whatsoever, I have no idea how to debug it

Comment: Press F12 in Chrome or run Firebug in Firefox, Open console and network connections, watch what happens there.

Comment: Thanks Andrei, found that error header('Status: 403 Forbidden'); was sitting in json.php. (Bolshoe sposibo za pomosh)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found an error in my json.php.

The error that was causing all my problems is that I have had a following line of code

```
header('Status: 403 Forbidden');
```

Thanks to Andrej